# Como capturar apenas a primeira parte de um texto que encaixe na regex?

Tags: java, regex

```xml
<END>Av. Dr. Walter Belian, nº 2.230, Distrito Industrial, João Pessoa-PB, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0013-43 e Inscrição Estadual nº 16.218.7157; (NR) II - Sergipe, localizada na Rodovia BR-101, s/nº, km 133, Distrito Industrial, Estância-SE, com CNPJ nº 07.526.577/0012-62 e Inscrição Estadual nº 27.142.202-5; (NR) III - Camaçari, localizada na Rua João Úrsulo, nº 1.620, Polo Petroquímico, Camaçari-BA</END>, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0015-05e Inscrição Estadual nº 110.250.399;
```

É o seguinte: acima se encontra um texto e abaixo a regex a capturar a informação do texto. Algo que deve levar em conta, é o que texto de onde a regex fará a captura, é um texto semiestruturado e possui algumas repetições. Abaixo encontra-se a regex. Para contextualizar, é uma regex que captura endereços.

> , (estabelecida|localizada|estabelecido|localizado) (na|no|em) ([^(Município|Estado)]([0-9A-Za-zçãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\Q() <>,º°ª-.;/'\"\E]+)-\s*[A-Z]{2})

Eu desejo capturar cada um dos endereços existentes no documento e pôr cada um  dos endereços entre as tags `<END>` e `</END>`. É considerado endereço, apenas a parte delimitada por

> ([0-9A-Za-zçãàáâéêíóôõúÂÃÁÀÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÇ\Q() <>,º°ª-.;/'\"\E]+)-\s*[A-Z]{2})

Ou seja, o restante é considerado "texto normal", que não deve ser capturado, mas não deve ser descartado. Então, para o exemplo dado, espara-se que fique assim:

```xml
<END>Av. Dr. Walter Belian, nº 2.230, Distrito Industrial, João Pessoa-PB</END>, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0013-43 e Inscrição Estadual nº 16.218.7157; (NR) II - Sergipe, localizada na <END>Rodovia BR-101, s/nº, km 133, Distrito Industrial, Estância-SE</END>, com CNPJ nº 07.526.577/0012-62 e Inscrição Estadual nº 27.142.202-5; (NR) III - Camaçari, localizada na <END>Rua João Úrsulo, nº 1.620, Polo Petroquímico, Camaçari-BA</END>, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0015-05 e Inscrição Estadual nº 110.250.399;
```

Porém, como se pode observar pelo texto, apenas pego todos os endereços de uma vez só. Pensei em usar regex, pois é assim que vinha capturando outras coisas. Mas caso haja qualquer maneira que possa solucionar, ótimo.

Comment: Qual parte exatamente do texto precisa capturar?

Comment: @MagicHat cada um dos fragmentos do texto que estejam entre <END> e </END> (segundo código).

Comment: <END>Av. Dr. Walter Belian, nº 2.230, Distrito Industrial, João Pessoa-PB</END>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vejo que no seu texto, os diferentes endereços estão separados por ponto-e-vírgula. Isso deixa a tarefa bem simples:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Enderecos {

    private static String localizarInicio(String s) {
        String[] loc = {"estabelecida ", "estabelecido ", "localizada ", "localizado "};
        String[] cj = {"em ", "na ", "no "};
        for (String a : loc) {
            for (String b : cj) {
                if (s.contains(a + b)) return s.replace(a + b, a + b + "<END>");
            }
        }
        return "<END>" + s;
    }

    private static String localizarFim(String s) {
        String busca = ", com CNPJ";
        if (s.contains(busca)) return s.replace(busca, "</END>" + busca);
        return s + "</END>";
    }

    public static String formatarListaEnderecos(String malformatado) {
        return Arrays
                .asList(malformatado.split(";"))
                .stream()
                .map(t -> t.replace("<END>", "").replace("</END>", "").trim())
                .filter(t -> !t.isEmpty())
                .map(Enderecos::localizarInicio)
                .map(Enderecos::localizarFim)
                .collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "<END>Av. Dr. Walter Belian, nº 2.230, Distrito Industrial, João Pessoa-PB, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0013-43e Inscrição Estadual nº 16.218.7157; (NR) II - Sergipe, localizada na Rodovia BR-101, s/nº, km 133, Distrito Industrial, Estância-SE, com CNPJ nº 07.526.577/0012-62 e Inscrição Estadual nº 27.142.202-5; (NR) III - Camaçari, localizada na Rua João Úrsulo, nº 1.620, Polo Petroquímico, Camaçari-BA, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0015-05e Inscrição Estadual nº 110.250.399;<END>";
        String formatado = formatarListaEnderecos(texto);
        System.out.println(formatado);
    }
}
```

O método que fiz com o propósito de fazer o que você quer é o `formatarListaEnderecos(String)`. Esse método faz o seguinte:

1. Divide tudo nos ponto-e-vírgulas, gerando um array de endereços, que é então convertido em uma lista e em um `Stream`.
2. Retira as tags "`<END>`" e "`</END>`" que já existirem de cada endereço, vez que não estarão aplicadas corretamente de início (serão recolocadas depois).
3. Retira espaços no começo e no final de cada endereço com o `trim()`.
4. Elimina os "endereços" que se reduzirem apenas a strings vazias.
5. Localiza onde colocar o "`<END>`" e o coloca em cada endereço.
6. Localiza onde colocar o "`</END>`" e o coloca em cada endereço.
7. Junta tudo em uma string só e retorna o resultado.

O local onde é colocado o "`<END>`" é determinado pelo método `localizarInicio(String)`. Ele procura por `"(estabelecid|localizad)(o|a) (em|na|no) "` e coloca a `<END>` depois. Se não achar nada, ele põe no começo de tudo.

O local onde é colocado o "`</END>`" é antes do texto `", com CNPJ"`. Se ele não encontrar isso, põe no final.

O método `main(String[])` está aí para que você possa testar esse método. Ao executá-lo, eis a saída:

```xml
<END>Av. Dr. Walter Belian, nº 2.230, Distrito Industrial, João Pessoa-PB</END>, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0013-43e Inscrição Estadual nº 16.218.7157(NR) II - Sergipe, localizada na <END>Rodovia BR-101, s/nº, km 133, Distrito Industrial, Estância-SE</END>, com CNPJ nº 07.526.577/0012-62 e Inscrição Estadual nº 27.142.202-5(NR) III - Camaçari, localizada na <END>Rua João Úrsulo, nº 1.620, Polo Petroquímico, Camaçari-BA</END>, com CNPJ nº 07.526.557/0015-05e Inscrição Estadual nº 110.250.399
```

Quanto ao uso de regex, acho que a ideia de usá-las nisso é um exemplo de [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132). Ou seja, acho que você está olhando para uma ferramenta que talvez não seja a melhor para resolver esse problema.

Comment: Victor, creio que compreendi sobre o problema XY e também sua solução, mas infelizmente ela não me satisfaz. Não por não usar regex, que talvez não seja a melhor solução, como alertado por você, pois talvez não funcione, mas sim que, por eu não deixar claro, o que seria endereço, que é apenas o grupo 3. Reformulei a questão para que ficasse mais claro e modifiquei o texto de exemplo, que punha a tag final no lugar errado, é depois de "Camaçari-BA", não após todo texto apresentado. Obrigado.

Comment: @JNMarcos Resposta atualizada.